# My hover: in tailwind CSS is not working for custom colors

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I have written this code and am using Next.js with Typescript and Tailwind. I want am calling this Header_2 as something to display like a component display in a component library. Initially the custom colors were not working but I made it work using the pattern in the `tailwind.config.ts`. The issue was that they were removed when building the css file. The source from where I solved this issue.
[https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/tailwind-extend-colors-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
export default function Header_2() {
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-16 flex justify-between items-center border-b-[1px] border-aui_border px-12 bg-aui_primary">
      <div className="h-full w-[10rem] flex justify-center items-center">
        <Link href="" className="h-full flex justify-center items-center">
          <Image src={Logo} alt="Logo" className="h-[50%] object-contain" />
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="h-full flex items-center gap-6">
        <Link href="" className="text-aui_text_secondary hover:text-aui_text">
          Field 1
        </Link>
        <Link href="" className="text-aui_text_secondary hover:text-aui_text">
          Field 2
        </Link>
        <Link href="" className="text-aui_text_secondary hover:text-aui_text">
          Field 3
        </Link>
        <div>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <Image src={Github} alt="Github Image" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <Link
          href="/signin"
          className="w-20 h-8 rounded-md bg-aui_accent hover:bg-aui_accent_hover text-aui_text_accent text-center flex justify-center items-center"
        >
          Login
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the code of my `tailwind.config.ts`

```js
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "var(--border)",

        //Website
        background: "var(--background)",
        foreground: "var(--foreground)",
        accent: "var(--accent)",
        accentLight: "var(--accent-light)",
        primary: "var(--primary)",
        primaryHover: "var(--primary-foreground)",
        secondary: "var(--secondary)",

        textPrimary: "var(--text-primary)",
        textSecondary: "var(--text-secondary)",
        textComplementary: "var(--text-complementary)",

        // Atlantic UI styles
        aui_primary: "var(--aui-primary)",
        aui_text: "var(--aui-text)",
        aui_text_secondary: "var(--aui-text-secondary)",
        aui_accent: "var(--aui-accent)",
        aui_accent_hover: "var(--aui-accent-hover)",
        aui_text_accent: "var(--aui-text-accent)",
        aui_accent_secondary: "var(--aui-accent-secondary)",
        aui_border: "var(--aui-border)",
      },
    },
    screens: {
      lg: { max: "1200px" },
      md: { max: "1000px" },
      sm: { max: "600px" },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern:
        /(bg|text|border)-(aui_primary|aui_text|aui_text_secondary|aui_accent|aui_accent_hover|aui_text_accent|aui_accent_secondary|aui_border)/,
    },
    {
      pattern:
        /(hover):(bg|text|border)-(aui_primary|aui_text|aui_text_secondary|aui_accent|aui_accent_hover|aui_text_accent|aui_accent_secondary|aui_border)/,
    },
  ],
};
export default config;
```

I have added a similar hover property to the safelist thinking that it should fix the issue but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variants for regular expression `safelist` entries are added [via the `variants` key](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) for the entry. Thus you should be able to combine both your entries into one as follows:

```js
safelist: [
  {
    pattern:
      /(bg|text|border)-(aui_primary|aui_text|aui_text_secondary|aui_accent|aui_accent_hover|aui_text_accent|aui_accent_secondary|aui_border)/,
    variants: ['hover'],
  },
],
```

Comment: Thank You. This solved my problem completely.